# geom_point legend colors have inverted shape overlays instead of actual shape

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

You can see in the below picture that the 'colour' legend is not acting correctly. I am expecting a colored circle (For example color one should be a green circle), however the background is green and you can see the black overlay of what appears to be some type of bounding box.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
library(ggmap)

c_map <- c(left = -86.817417, bottom = 36.133247, right = -86.793141, top = 36.153650)
campus <- get_stamenmap(c_map, zoom = 15, maptype = "toner-lines")

some_data <- read.csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/pconwell/085c1413e418adaa7c1e203c9680a0f8/raw/c7a3e5f7aa900de6bc2bcccd5dc5d9b8f7e31b81/some_data.csv')

ggmap(campus, darken = c(0.33, "white"), extent = "device") + 

  stat_density2d(data = some_data,
                 aes(x = longitude,
                     y = latitude,
                     fill = stat(nlevel),
                     alpha = stat(nlevel)),
                 size = 2,
                 bins = 12,
                 geom = "polygon"
  ) +

  scale_fill_gradientn(guide = "colorbar",
                       colours = c("#adddd1", "#3e98af", "#375980"),
                       breaks=c(0.2, 0.9), 
                       labels=c("Least","Most"), 
                       name = "Heat Map"
  ) +

  geom_point(data = some_data,
             aes(x = longitude,
                 y = latitude,
                 color = color,
                 shape = shape),
             alpha = .75,
             size = 4

  )  +

  scale_alpha_continuous(range = c(0.33, 0.66), 
                         guide = FALSE
  )
```

How can I get the legend to show the colors correctly? The icons appear correctly in the map, but do not show correctly in the legend.

Comment: Not directly about the problem, but suggestion: getting basemaps with `ggmap` requires a Google maps API key. Swapping the `ggmap` call with just `ggplot` on your dataset removes the requirement for an API key but still recreates the problem, making it easier for more folks to help

Comment: Odd, I haven't had to use an API key that I recall - but I'm also stamen maps if that makes a difference. I'll look at using ggplot instead though.

Comment: I think it's based on updates a while back that you generally need an API key. `ggmap` also just isn't essential to the problem. It seems like you have a size argument in the density that might be a holdover from a previous version? There isn't anything in the density layer that needs a size, but that `size = 2` is what creates the size 2 border around the color legend points--delete that argument and no more borders

Comment: I guess I entered an API key a while back - I don't remember and ggmap hasn't complained about it so... But back to your point, swapping `ggplot` for `ggmap` gives me the error `Error: 'data' must be a data frame, or other object coercible by 'fortify()', not an S3 object with class ggmap/raster` which I am guessing is related to `get_stamenmap()` which I haven't figured out how to work around yet. But I'll keep looking.

Comment: Substitute `size = 2` in the `stat_density2d` with `color = 'transparent'`; the polygon stroke is getting picked up by the legend.

Comment: @alistaire - you are a genius, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background and the bounding box come from the legend for colour of a polygon. Here’s a little simpler reproducible example:

```r
library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 3.5.3

set.seed(42)
df <- as.data.frame(MASS::mvrnorm(100, c(0, 0), matrix(c(1, .6), 2, 2)))

ggplot(df, aes(V1, V2)) +
  stat_density_2d(geom = "polygon") +
  geom_point(aes(colour = cut_number(V1, 5)))
```

[image]

You can fix this by explicitly setting the colour of the polygon geom:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(V1, V2)) +
  stat_density_2d(geom = "polygon", colour = NA) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = cut_number(V1, 5)))
```

[image]

However, I’m a bit surprised that the polygon legend shows up even though the associated layer doesn’t have anything mapped to colour. Perhaps this is a bug?

**UPDATE:** I couldn’t reproduce this behaviour with other geoms or stats, so I looked into density 2d a bit more: Strangely enough, it seems like the colour legend for the polygon appears because `StatDensity2d` has a default aesthetic value for colour:

```r
StatDensity2d$default_aes
#> Aesthetic mapping: 
#> * `colour` -> "#3366FF"
#> * `size`   -> 0.5
StatDensity2d$default_aes <- aes()

ggplot(df, aes(V1, V2)) +
  stat_density_2d(geom = "polygon") +
  geom_point(aes(colour = cut_number(V1, 5)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-07-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

A simplified version of the problem (removing the requirement for `ggmap` and a Google API key) shows that it's mostly about superfluous arguments. Take the code apart layer by later, since those layers build up what gets included in the legend. The size argument in your `stat_density2d` doesn't do anything with the geom set to polygon; it would only make sense for contours, such as:

```r
library(ggplot2)

some_data <- read.csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/pconwell/085c1413e418adaa7c1e203c9680a0f8/raw/c7a3e5f7aa900de6bc2bcccd5dc5d9b8f7e31b81/some_data.csv')

ggplot(some_data, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = color, shape = shape), alpha = 0.75, size = 4) +
  stat_density2d(aes(alpha = stat(nlevel)),
                 size = 2) + 
  guides(alpha = "none",
         color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = NA)))
```

[image]

There you see the effect of `size = 2` in both the density and the legend, where it shows as a thick line in the color legend.

Since this isn't necessary for the polygons, remove the size argument or set it to 0. You also had a fill element coming in from the density layer, making those darkened areas on the legend. Remove that by explicitly setting the fill to `NA` in the legend.

```r
ggplot(some_data, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = color, shape = shape), alpha = 0.75, size = 4) +
  stat_density2d(aes(fill = stat(nlevel), alpha = stat(nlevel)),
                 size = 0,
                 geom = "polygon") + 
  guides(alpha = "none",
         color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = NA)))
```

[image]

Comment: When I run your example, I still get the border for the colour legend in the second plot. I think this is due to the graphics device (I'm on Windows), as when I rendered with the `Cairo_png()` device, the borders were gone: zero width, I assume.

Comment: @MikkoMarttila weird. I'm on a Mac and don't have anything else available to test on, but graphics devices can be finicky